# Gradle fails to resolve dependency through Nexus but artifacts downloads in browser

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, nexus, sonatype

Gradle fails to resolve dependency via Nexus Repository where as the artifacts are downloadable through browser. I have the following error

> Error:Could not find ecj.jar
>   (org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.6.1). Searched in the following
>   locations:
>       http://infynexus/nexus/content/groups/Manoj.P04/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.6.1/ecj-4.6.1.jar

but this jar is downloadable in the browser
[Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXZp7.png)

**build.gradle**

> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         maven {
>             credentials {
>                 username mavenUser
>                 password mavenPassword
>             }
>             url 'http://infynexus/nexus/content/groups/Manoj.P04/'
>         }
>
>     }
>
>
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
>
>         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>         // in the individual module build.gradle files
>     }
> }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         maven {
>             credentials {
>                 username mavenUser
>                 password mavenPassword
>             }
>             url 'infynexus/nexus/content/groups/Manoj.P04/'
>         }
>
>         task clean(type: Delete) {
>             delete rootProject.buildDir
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

**gradle.properties**

> ```
> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
>
> mavenUser=xxxx
> mavenPassword=xxx
> ```

Comment: Hi #Manoj, Facing same problem ?

Comment: There is some problem with Android Studio cache. I went to the following location C:\Users\manoj.p04\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib and found out that ecj-4.6.1.jar was present. I deleted that and syched, everything works fine now

Answer (score 6):

In my case **refreshing the gradle dependencies worked**.
e.g. I executed `gradle clean --refresh-dependencies` once. And then the builds worked normally again.

**Details**:

I got the same error-message as the original answer:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':m15_android_lib:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find constraint-layout-solver.jar (com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.1.0/constraint-layout-solver-1.1.0.jar
```

The Nexus Repository browser showed only the `.pom` file for that dependency, but not the `.jar`.
I could also download the `.jar` file from my local Nexus: e.g. entering the URL directly in Chrome.
But the gradle build still failed to resolve the dependency.

Just some thoughts, if this should happen again:

- Maybe it's a problem in **Nexus** (since it shows only the pom but also has the jar): in this case we can try to:

  - **Invalidate the caches** of the Repository (and maybe the Repository Group)
    This can be done when you log-in as admin and go to `Manage Repositories`
  - **Restart** the Nexus service
- I think it may be related to **Gradle** itself (since `--refresh-dependencies` resolved the issue). So maybe just **stop**ping the **gradle daemon** (with : `gradle --stop`) is also enough.
- If it is really related to **Android Studio** caching, we could also try to **restart** Android Studio or use `File`- `Invalidate caches/restart`.

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with Android Studio cache. I went to the following location:

> C:\Users\manoj.p04\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib

and ecj-4.6.1.jar was present. I deleted the jar and resynched, everything works fine now..

Thanks